# Is this the solution of this 2-form integration?

Tags: calculus, integration, differential-forms

Let $\omega = x^2 dz \wedge dy + (y+z)(dx \wedge dy + dx \wedge dz)$ be a 2-form on $\mathbb R^3$. Let $S$ be the surface of rotation around the x axis of the function $f(t)=1+t^2$, $0 < t < 1$. Calculate $\int_S\omega$.

The surface $S$ is parametrized by $\varphi: [0, 1]\times[0, 2\pi] \to \mathbb R^3$
$\\ \varphi(t, \theta) = (t, (1+t^2)\cos\theta,(1+t^2)\sin\theta)\\$

The Jacobian is
\begin{bmatrix}1&2t\cos\theta&2t\sin\theta\\0&-(1+t^2)\sin\theta&(1+t^2)\cos\theta
\end{bmatrix}

$dx\wedge dz \to (1+t^2)\cos\theta dtd\theta\\
dx\wedge dy \to -(1+t^2)\sin\theta dtd\theta
\\dy\wedge dz = 2t(1+t^2)dtd\theta$

So I simply transformed
$\int_S\omega =\\ \int_0^1\int_0^{2\pi} -t^2(1+t^2)2t dtd\theta 
\\+\int_0^1\int_0^{2\pi}(1+t^2)^2(\cos^2\theta - \sin^2\theta)dtd\theta$

The last term goes away as
$\int_0^{2\pi} \cos^\theta - \sin^2\theta d\theta = 0$.
The firs term simply gives

$-4\pi\int_0^1t^3+t^5dt = -4\pi(1/4+1/6) = -\pi(1+2/3) = -\pi\frac{5}{3}$

Comment: You need to show your work so we can check it instead of duplicating effort. Also, your approach is more important than the final answer.

Comment: Sorry, I was in a hurry, now I added a solution

Comment: Yes that is correct work.

Comment: One small nitpick: saying $dx\wedge dz\to (1+t^2)\cos\theta\,dt\,d\theta$, 
is a little ambiguous technically speaking. What does the arrow $\to$ mean here? How does $dx\wedge dz$ "become" $(1+t^2)\cos\theta\,dt\,d\theta$? Well, now that you're learning about differential forms, you have all the tools necessary to formally phrase this. The correct assertion is that the pull back via the parametrization is $\varphi^*(dx\wedge dz)= (1+t^2)\cos\theta\,dt\wedge d\theta$. Likewise for the other two terms.